# How to draw person outline sketch java android

Tags: java, android

I want to create outline sketch of the person like this. Is there any API?

[image]

I'm detecting a person and cropping only the person and also getting foreground but I do not have idea how to draw that person's outline like the shown image anyone have idea how to do it?

```
private void createImageTransactor(Bitmap image) {
    MLImageSegmentationSetting setting = new MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory().setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.BODY_SEG).create();
    this.analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(setting);
    if (this.isChosen(image)) {
        MLFrame mlFrame = new MLFrame.Creator().setBitmap(image).create();
        Task<MLImageSegmentation> task = this.analyzer.asyncAnalyseFrame(mlFrame);
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<MLImageSegmentation>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(MLImageSegmentation mlImageSegmentationResults) {

                if (mlImageSegmentationResults != null) {
                    try {
                        cutImage = mlImageSegmentationResults.getForeground();

                       
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext() ,getResources().getString(R.string.Fail), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext() ,getResources().getString(R.string.Fail), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.txt_not_detect_human, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know opencv has such a function - its called Canny: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html

Comment: can we without using OpenCV?

Comment: If you want to write it entirely by yourself then it might be too broad question to ask here. If you want to use specific API then I suggest you add appropriate tag to your question.